# How to get child object key using a value?

Tags: javascript, filter

I have nested object as follows,

```
 {
  "Types": {
    "TEST": {
      "name": "EC",
      "alloweMultipls": "true"
    },
    "TEST1": {
      "name": "ED",
      "alloweMultipls": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

how can i retrive **`allowMyltipls`** if i have only the key **`"EC"`** not any other value.

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach. You can get all properties of the `fileTypes` object and then iterate over them using `.filter` function and find that property for which the `name` equals to your `key`. Then with that key retrieve the nested object.

```js
const object = {
  "fileTypes": {
    "TEST": {
      "name": "EC",
      "alloweMultipls": "true"
    },
    "TEST1": {
      "name": "ED",
      "alloweMultipls": "true"
    }
  }
};

const key = 'EC';
const fileTypes = object.fileTypes;

const property= Object.keys(fileTypes).filter(item => fileTypes[item].name === key);

console.log(fileTypes[property]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your object and check the 'name' property, if it matches to your desired then get the full object. Simple and elegant solution.

```js
var data = {
  "Types": {
    "TEST": {
      "name": "EC",
      "alloweMultipls": "true"
    },
    "TEST1": {
      "name": "ED",
      "alloweMultipls": "true"
    }
  }
};

for(d in data.Types){
    if(data.Types[d].name=='EC'){
        console.log(data.Types[d]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ataur Rahman,

```
 var data = {  "Types": {
"TEST": {
  "name": "EC",
  "alloweMultipls": "true"
},
"TEST1": {
  "name": "ED",
  "alloweMultipls": "true"
}  }}


 var allMultiplesInEC = [];


for(var i=0;i<data.Types.length-1;++i){  if(data.Types[i].name =='EC'{

 allMultiplesInEC.push(data.Types[i].alloweMultipls);}
}

console.log(allMultiplesInEC);
```